# assign variable from complex command

Tags: bash, shell, ksh

I'm trying to assign a variable using another variable that is being read in from a while and also being parsed at the same time. However, for some reason I'm not able to get the new variable to get the data i want. Any help would be appreciated.

```
while read line
do
    foldername=$($line | awk -F'/' '{ print $4 }')
    echo $foldername
done < folderlist.txt
```

folderlist.txt contains a list of directory where i'm trying to read the 4th parameter.

Comment: `$line | awk -F'/' '{ print $4 }'` alone is wrong. You should `echo "$line" | awk -F'/' '{ print $4 }'` or `awk -F'/' '{ print $4 }' <<< "$line"`. Also, if you are getting the filename you can consider using `basename $line`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! That works. I just did foldername=$(echo "$line" | awk -F'/' '{ print $4 }')

Answer (score 1):

why not:
awk '{ print $4 }' folderlist.txt   ?
The problem in your script fragment above may be that you're executing contents of $line as command, rather than merely parsing it, where you do $( $line ... | awk ... )

Comment: Thanks! This works also. foldername=$(awk -F'/' '{ print $4 }' <<< "$line"). what i'm trying to do is get the 4th parameter..then create a new folder under a new directory using that 4th parameter.

Comment: ah, ok.  then don't read whole line into one variable, but fields 1, 2, 3, 4, and rest into vars, from which you pick the var containing field 4:     `while read f1 f2 f3 f4 rest; do  echo "yourcommands $f4"; done < folderlist.txt` - no subshelling involved. changing field delimiter is done by assigning to variable IFS

Comment: `foo="a/b/c/d"; IFS="/"; while read f1 f2 f3 f4; do echo $f3; done <<< "$foo"` gives an idea how to use that.  - this 5 minute limit on editing comments makes testing on the go a bit hard, sorry.